# Excel VBA Evaluate function

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

I would like to use the column number of a cell as a variable in a for loop by using the Evaluate function.
Here is the first part of the code:

```
Sub search()
Dim whe As Integer
 
lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrow
For j = 3 To 4

If Cells(i, j).Value = Range("G2").Value Then
whe = Evaluate("=COLUMN(" & Cells(i, j).Address(0, 0) & ")")

If whe = 3 Then
do something
```

However, I get a "Run-time error 13: Type mismatch" message at the If statement.
I have tried to define the "whe" variable as Integer or Variant but neither of them worked.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Isn't this overcomplicating things? `j` is the column.

Comment: Yes, j is the column nonetheless, I would like to know why I am receiving error regarding the Evalaute function.

Comment: I think the issue is that it is returning an array which gives VBA a hissy fit. This seems to work `MsgBox Evaluate("=INDEX(COLUMN(" & Cells(2, 3).Address(0, 0) & "),1)")`.

Comment: @SJR good find! Alternately `Evaluate("=COLUMN(" & Cells(i, j).Address(0, 0) & ")")(1)`.

Comment: Yes, it is the IF statement that throws an error. But the result of my evaluate function is a number not an array. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Nevertheless, the Evaluate("=COLUMN(" & Cells(i, j).Address(0, 0) & ")")(1) formula worked, thank you very much! Could you please shortly explain the logic of (1) at the end?

Comment: The point is that whatever you or I might think it is not returning a number, it is returning an array, hence the error. See BigBen's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the result of my evaluate function is a number not an array.

Using [`VarType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function), the result of `Evaluate("=COLUMN(" & Cells(i, j).Address(0, 0) & ")")` is actually an array.

It is a one-based array (verified using [`LBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/lbound-function)), so

```
whe = Evaluate("=COLUMN(" & Cells(i, j).Address(0, 0) & ")")(1)
```

assigns its first element to `whe`.

> I have tried to define the "whe" variable as Integer or Variant but neither of them worked.

Assigning to a `Variant` definitely works here, so I suspect you were referring to an unresolved error in the `If` statement, not the `Evaluate`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! Everything is clear now and I was wrong that first, the error is relating to the Evaluate and second, I thought that the result of the Evaluate is not an array. Thanks again!